# Smaller textwidth in memoir

Tags: margins, memoir

I have to use `memoir` with A4-paper and 11pt font size. This way the lines are very long, so I would like to make it smaller to have less characters per line. However when just setting parameters that seem to do that, such as `settypeblocksize`, `checkandfixthelayout` gives an error [1], which appears to indicate that it is necessary to layout the whole page by hand then.

In KOMA-Script, the DIV option just adapts all values accordingly. Is there a similar option for `memoir`?

[1] A MWE reproducing this (I do not know whether this approach does what I need):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext} 

\settypeblocksize{0.9\stockheight}{0.9\stockwidth}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

produces this error:

```
./a.tex:6: Class memoir Error: \spinemargin (113.26999pt) and/or \textwidth (537.75343pt) and/or \foremargin (115.23788pt) are too large for \paperwidth (597.50787pt) by 168.75343pt.
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal compilable example starting from `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` so we could reproduce that problem?

Comment: FYI: This question has also been asked on a [german forum](http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=76338), but didn't get any reactions yet.

Comment: Currently `memoir` does not readjust the margins. Thus you have you adjust the left/right and upper/lower margins accordingly. And BTW pleasee provide minimal examples when asking questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the MWE, as mentioned `memoir` does not readjust the margins then the textblock is changed. Thus since you now have a textwidth of `0.9\paperwidth` the textwidth plus the original left and right margins are wider than the `\paperwidth`

With `\settypeblocksize` I usually go for something similar to

```
\settypeblocksize{0.9\stockheight}{0.9\stockwidth}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.2}
\setulmargins{*}{*}{1.4}
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]
```

(I often use the golden ratio)